# is sqlitejdbc driver included in sqlite or default java installation on linux system

Tags: database, sqlite, sqlitejdbc

I installed liquibase in my ubuntu to work with sqlite, which requires sqlitejdbc driver to run. I can not find if this driver was already installed when I was installing sqlite 6 months ago. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you'll need to get it yourself. There are two slightly different versions provided by different groups:

http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/

http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC